# How Siemens 7SJ80 over current protection relay can trip a circuit breaker remotelly installed

Tags: relay, over-voltage-protection, automatic-circuit-breaker

I wanted to know about the Siemens 7SJ80 protection relay which is installed in a transformer station on the middle-voltage line.
How can I trip a circuit breaker installed between a solar generation and a customer installation box? Does the circuit breaker have to be integrated with a motor drive?

Comment: First, shouldn't you be asking the sales person about this question? Those devices go for enough money to pay for some support -- at the very least, some phone support from a technical FAE. Second, you need to write a lot more here, I think. My crystal ball isn't functional right now.

Comment: Looks like if you Google for "Siemens 7SJ80" you can find all the technical documentation on Siemens' web sites.